# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL with Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: javascript, razor

My Code
{

```
  var textarea='@Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Content)'
    $('#boxPhanThuong').append(textarea);
```

}

In console I had:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it. Html.textboxbor or dropdownlistfor is fine but Html.textareafor is not.

Comment: thanks for your help @JonathanLonowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Content)` given to the browser likely includes line breaks.

Simple example:

```
var textarea='<textarea id="Content">
</textarea>';
```

And, in JavaScript, string literals don't allow line breaks to be included verbatim. They have to be escaped, which Razor isn't going to do for you.

---

You can however take advantage of JavaScript and JSON's similarities, along with [`Json.Encode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode.aspx), to output the markup so JavaScript understands it. Though, this requires additional setup:

```
var textarea=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content).ToHtmlString()));
```

The other additions are:

- [`.ToHtmlString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.tohtmlstring.aspx) to give `Json.Encode()` a `string` rather than an `object`.
- [`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740.aspx) to prevent the result from `Json.Encode()` becoming HTML-encoded – `&quot;&lt;textarea ...` – since a `<script>` won't understand those.

For the simple example, the result of this would be:

```
var textarea="<textarea id=\"Content\">\n</textarea>";
```

Comment: i use json.encode()
var textarea=@Json.Encode(Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content)).....
But the result of this was:
var textare={}

Comment: @AnhQuốcLê Sorry. I've updated the snippet and explanation.